# Acessing request attribute in jsp (Spring 3 mvc)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

iam using a very basic basic basic controller in spring mvc

```
...
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {

        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        return new ModelAndView("helloteste", "message", message);
    }
...
```

but when accessing it from a jsp, nothing is shown.
Jsp bellow

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series: Hello World </title>
</head>
<body>
${message}

</body>
</html>
```

Result on the screen (the server does not resolve the tag ...)

```
${message}
```

However if i get te info directely from the attributes of the request, it works ...

```
<%
String s = (String ) request.getAttribute("message");
out.print(s);

%>
```

Why the notation ${...} is not working ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as if the JSP is not resolving the expression language.  This can be a configuration issue if your web.xml file does not specify a `version` attribute of 2.4 or greater for the `<web-app/>` tag.  In this case, I would recommend updating your web.xml file to following, provided that your app server is modern enough:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

</web-app>
```

Comment: tried, did not worked. Still getting ${model.message} on the browser

Comment: What version of JSP are you using?  Its like it doesn't want to resolve the EL.  In your web.xml file, what is the version on the web-app tag?  http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/ServletsWebXml

Comment: None, just  <web-app>    ---- header <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

Comment: The web.xml must specify version 2.4 or higher to use JSP EL, it appears your using 2.3.  Follow the link provided to change the web.xml config.

Comment: Just curious, what app server are you using?